# PowerApps with SharePoint Versus ASP.NET core with SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-core, sharepoint, office365

I have around 6 years of experience in SharePoint, ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET Core MVC & SQL Server. Now when I want to take a decision, if the project should be implemented using SharePoint/PowerApps or using SQL-Server/ASP.NET-MVC, is the complexity of the relation between the entities. The less complex the more I go with SharePoint/PowerApps. But one of the main concerns I have found recently and one of the main differences is the upgrade time/effort required by both technologies to stay supported by Microsoft.

Now in ASP.NET Core, Microsoft release new .NET core versions every 2 years and the new .NET version become out of support each 3 years, while if we develop our app using Power apps and SharePoint, we will not face this support issue, am I correct?

**Can I say that using SharePoint/PowerApps will be more reliable and will require less effort/time to stay supported by Microsoft? Any comments or thoughts?**

Comment: sharepoint is end of life in 2026 right?

Comment: @Ewan SharePoint online end of life? never heard of that

Comment: @Ewan based on this link SharePoint onpremsies will end on 2026 @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/end-of-support/end-of-support-2026 not the online version which i am using

Comment: the online version gets updated twice a year, its unclear to me what the support policy for specific versions is? I do share your confusion about the support for net 5/6/7 etc it seems crazy that they are effectively saying your programs will not run after 3 years. Why would I move off net framework 4.8 with indefinite support?

Comment: @Ewan yes it is crazy and confusing, so you mean .net 4.8 will be supported for unspecific date as for today April 2023?

Comment: yeah 4.8 is good forever as it stands, which just begs the question of what's the real date. My worry about the online sharepoint would be features changing and being deprecated over time without any official guarantee on lifespan.

Comment: @Ewan so did you ever develop and production app on .net core? not sure how the companies all around the world deal with this 3 years end of life??? as many comapnies already invest a lot of .net core and get away from traditional .net

Comment: yeah all our stuff is being upgraded to 6 and even 7, framework is seen as old hat. It makes no sense if you look at the numbers, but I think there is a bigger picture

Comment: @Ewan so you mean you currently works on .net 6 and .net 7 web projects? if so, then what are you plans for the upgrades ?

Comment: yeah, plan = just keep updating every year

Comment: @Ewan why every year? you can do it each 3 years , am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

It is a short lifespan, I would worry that in practice Sharepoint Online has the same lifetime for any given version as they update automatically twice a year.

The bigger picture I think is how long do you need your software to last, *without updating*.

1. Line of business applications.

   These are constantly being updated with new features as the business changes. Updating from net core to 5 to  6 to 7 is trivial compared to the other stuff you need to do.
2. Stand alone enterprise software.

   Each year you want to sell a new version, office 95, 97, 2000 etc. You don't want to support *your* old versions, so why would microsoft?
3. Stand alone consumer software.

   Halo 2 or something. You would like it to run forever without touching it, and 3 years is probably too short and would annoy your customers. But after end of life, it will still run with the right runtime installed, it's just not recommended.
4. Stand alone embedded systems

   Blood transfusion monitor, communications satellite, Car built in satnav. It MUST run forever without updates, but the OS isn't going to change or get updates either. So you prob have a customised, cut down, locked down OS that you won't update barring an emergency. But you are probably coding in c++ anyway.

Comment: for my case i work as a freelancer and one of my customer (who have a SharePoint online) want to develop a web application which is more suitable to be developed using ASP.NET Core rather than SharePoint Online,, but not sure how they need to run the .NET 6 project after November 2024? or at least what i need to tell them? i will send them the source code after completing the UAT.. so they can upgrade or someone else,, but i think they need to know that the underlying .NET version will stop been supported after November 2024.. seems .net core is an overkill in such a case,, do you agree?

Comment: I guess that comes under 3. although, surely the simple answer is to ask them whether they want one or the other. I agree 3 years is short. but windows 10 is eol in 2025